# Unable to click on webpage based on attribute results

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to navigate in "https://www.ford.co.uk/shop/price-and-locate/build-and-price-gf3#/catalogID/WAEGB-CE1-2015-B479FiestaCarGBR201950/?code=". I have to select Titanium in the model list. But i am not able to select it. Everytime the list of models will vary based on link.

Below is the code which i have tried.

```
Sub testcode()

Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLAs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLA As MSHTML.IHTMLElement


ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://www.ford.co.uk/shop/price-and-locate/build-and-price-gf3#/catalogID/WAEGB-CE1-2015-B479FiestaCarGBR201950/?code="
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

Set htmldoc = ie.document
Set HTMLAs = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("features-list-item feature-box")

    For Each HTMLA In HTMLAs
        Debug.Print HTMLA.getAttribute("id"), HTMLA.getAttribute("tabindex")
        If HTMLA.getAttribute("id") = "feature-1" And HTMLA.getAttribute("tabindex") = 0 Then
            HTMLA.Click
        End If
    Next HTMLA
Set HTMLAs = Nothing
Set HTMLA = Nothing


End Sub
```

The result should be webpage loaded and selected the titanium series. Kindly assist me achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTMLA` itself doesn't seem to have a click handler, but you can click on one of its child elements.

Try this:

```
If HTMLA.getAttribute("id") = "feature-1" And HTMLA.getAttribute("tabindex") = 0 Then
    HTMLA.getElementsByTagName("img")(0).Click
    Exit For
End If
```